# excel Check name and use mailaddres

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheeta with the name of a person (dropdown), in a different sheetb (from where the dropdown gets the name) are the contact details. 
If in sheeta a person is selected and the user pushes the send button the mail has to be sent to that person, mailaddress in sheetb.

How can i get the mailaddress from sheetb with a code in the mail macro?

Anyone ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setup a `VLOOPUP` in Sheet A which will fetch the email Id in a cell and then reference that in you code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask, but are you trying to sent email from within Excel or trying to sent information within Excel from one sheet to another? Perhaps you can provide screen shots of both sheets?

thanks,

Naveen

Comment: I want to email the worksheet, the code to send to email works fine only i want read  the mailaddres from a the input sheeta. In sheeta is the name a the person, in sheetb is the mailaddres of that person

Comment: It look like you just want to retrieve information from one sheet into the other. On that assumption here we go: 1. how do you know that in sheet B there is an email that corresponds with the email of a person in sheet A? If in sheet B there is the name of this person AND on sheet A the name of this person is there too than use the vlookup function in sheet A where you ask Excel to 1. find the name of the person in sheet B 2. go one place to the right when finding the name. It will then show up the email address of this person in Sheet A. Is this helpfull?